# Is zero copy principle supported in Mac

Tags: java, linux, macos, operating-system

Hi Trying to understand the zero copy principle. Wikipedia says

> Several operating systems support zero-copying of files through
>   specific APIs.
>
> The Linux kernel supports zero-copy through various system calls, such
>   as sys/socket.h's sendfile, sendfile64, and splice. Some of them are
>   specified in POSIX and thus also present in the BSD kernels or IBM
>   AIX, some are unique to the Linux kernel API.
>
> Microsoft Windows supports zero-copy through the TransmitFile API.
>
> Java input streams can support zero-copy through the
>   java.nio.channels.FileChannel's transferTo() method if the underlying
>   operating system also supports zero copy.[4]

I dont see any mention of OSX though It says present in BSD kernels.

But http://www.bigfastblog.com/zero-copy-transfer-data-faster-in-ruby blog says its not supported in OSX.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [man page for sendfile](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/sendfile.2.html) for OS X.  While it makes no reference to zero copy, it does refer to sendfile as a system call (as oppose to some wrapper around open/read/write/close) so I think it is pretty safe to assume that it doesn't involve copying a file to user-space.